# How can we perform "in" query on Elasticsearch in python, using elasticsearch_dsl?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a list, `id_list = [1, 3, 5, 7]`

I need to fetch data from elasticsearch corresponding to the ids present in id_list, similar to `id__in` that we do for postgres.

I was trying to find a way using `elasticsearch_dsl.Search()`, but I am stuck at it. Any help with the code or relevant documentation will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) to perform `"in"` query in elasticsearch

Try out the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "id_list": [
        1,
        3,
        5,
        7
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding on to your point, for python we can use something like this s.query(query).filter('terms', id=[1, 3, 5, 7])

Comment: @uglyCoder yes you can include `filter` clause as well if you are not concerned about the scoring part, and you just want to know whether the `id` matched or not